# "Evaluate" string into it's true type using Python

Tags: python, evaluation

I'm personally looking for a way to convert a string which includes bytecode into a bytecode type but I'm also curious if it is possible to do this process for essentially any variable type **without** using `eval`.

Working example using `eval`:

```py
a = "b'gAAAAABhI1vlZaaVcD7VcXpk5kEpqtn5ItujPJUnP92QgwUOc07ulG95YbCyn9M0zolk-z04GywKmGehChhrj27KA5BQVafQ8w=='"
print(type(eval(a)))
```

Output:

```py
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: "any type"? That means reinventing `eval()`, with all its consequences.

Comment: Wow, I somehow didn't see that the same question was asked. Either way, `ast.literal_eval` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with `str.encode`:

```
>>> a = "b'gAAAAABhI1vlZaaVcD7VcXpk5kEpqtn5ItujPJUnP92QgwUOc07ulG95YbCyn9M0zolk-z04GywKmGehChhrj27KA5BQVafQ8w=='"
>>> a[3:-2].encode()
b'AAAAABhI1vlZaaVcD7VcXpk5kEpqtn5ItujPJUnP92QgwUOc07ulG95YbCyn9M0zolk-z04GywKmGehChhrj27KA5BQVafQ8w='
>>>
```